# Add click function to Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var el = createWindow(WindowContent, {
    "id": window.id,
    "titleBar": {
        "enabled": true,
        "titleButtons": [
            {
                "type": "close",
                click : function(){ //function
                    window.close();
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});


function createWindow(el, prop){
...
        if(prop.titleBar.titleButtons.length !== undefined){
            for(var i = 0; i < prop.titleBar.titleButtons.length; i++){
                button = prop.titleBar.titleButtons[i];
                console.log(button);
                $('#'+prop.id).find("button[type='"+button.type+"']").click(button.click);
            }
        }
 }
```

How can i add the click function from the prop object to my button?
it just doesnt do anything.

`$('#'+prop.id).find("button[type='"+button.type+"']").click(button.click());`

I get an error because button.click is not a function

Fixed the problem by using `$('#'+prop.id).on("click", "button[type='"+button.type+"']", button.click);` instead of `$('#'+prop.id).find("button[type='"+button.type+"']").click(button.click());`

Comment: Actually [the code in the example works](http://jsfiddle.net/dx1ver8g/). If your actual code has the parentheses like in a separate line, then eosterberg's answer is the way to go, otherways we need more information. Notice also, that JS can only close windows it has opened. `window.close()` closes a browser window, not for example div elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#'+prop.id).find("button[type='"+button.type+"']").click(function(){
   console.log('event click called');
 });
```

Comment: Good idea! I always do that at first before something more complicated.

Comment: ye its not firing :C, thought i checked that.
The parent div has a mousedown event could this be a reason why it doesn't fire? 

`$('#'+prop.id).find("button[type='"+button.type+"']").css("background-color", "orange")` changes the background color tho

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you are not assigning the function for the click event, but the result of invoking the function. Try removing the 2 parenthesis at the end, from

```
.click(button.click());
```

To:

```
.click(button.click);
```

After that, try running just the .find statement to see if jQuery returns your button:

```
$('#'+prop.id).find("button[type='"+button.type+"']")
```

If not, i suspect your button[type=close] is incorrect

Comment: it is correct the click is just not firing i can change the background color `$('#'+prop.id).find("button[type='"+button.type+"']").css("background-color", "orange")`

Comment: If you just change button color on click, does that fire?

Comment: like: `this.style.backgroundColor='red';` in the click function